# How do I concatenate symbol-by-symbol two arrays

Tags: python, arrays

Im have 2 arrays, for example: [1, 2, 3] and [4, 5, 6] How do i merge them into 1 array?: [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6] ? help please

Comment: Use extend() list method

Comment: What have tried?

Comment: Write a `for` loop

Comment: `[y for t in zip(l1,l2) for y in t]`? if both are equal length lists.

Answer (score 1):

If the order is not important can just use `+`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = a + b
```

Otherwise you can do something like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = []
for i, j in zip(a, b):
    c += [i, j]
```